# Outer points of a image

Tags: c#, shapes

Given the following picture that represents a tilemap:

[image]

How do I find all the outer vertices in order to generate a nice polygon? Currently I have a quick and dirty approach that generates 4 points for each black pixel but its needs to be better.

Comment: What's your input? A real picture? Or a data structure? For a picture: Would it make sense to use one of the gazillion edge detection algorithms? Canny maybe? That'd basically give you the outline. If that isn't what you need: What DO you need?

Comment: I have a array of bytes that represent the tiles. Anything thats not 0 is filled and should be included if collision is on.

Comment: I think you should add your input and the result you are expecting.